# cv2_imshow collab doesnt show anything for predicting video using cnn+l;stm model

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, lstm

Hi guys i'm trying to test my model into video for prediction

i got no error log or anything

but nothing appear, i am trying to open the video and predict it using my cnn(alexnet)+lstm model

here are my **code**

```
model_path = 'Model/CCTV_10Frame_Adam_Model_1e2_b16_regul.h5'
model = models.load_model(model_path)

vid = cv2.VideoCapture("Data16_116.mp4")

while(True):
    ret, frame = vid.read()
    start = time.time()
    if ret:
        draw = frame.copy()
        draw = cv2.cvtColor(draw, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        scale_percent = 20 # percent of original size
        width = 299
        height = width
        dim = (width, height)
        frame_set = cv2.resize(draw, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
        frame_set=np.arange(10*width*height*3).reshape(10,width, height, 3)
        frame_set.reshape(10, width, height, 3).shape
        frame_set = np.expand_dims(frame_set, axis=0)
        result=model.predict(frame_set)
        
        cv2_imshow(result)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
        else:
            break

vid.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

does anyone know a thing about this?

any answer would be grateful

thank you so much !

Note : i did try it in vsc but sadly its only open for 1 second and the log saying

> Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 1.25GiB
> with freed_by_count=0. The caller indicates that this is not a
> failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if  more
> memory were available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"""Can you please check after remove the **else : break ** block from your code ? As it might be skipping the camera frame without validating any interrupt from user .
"""

```
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'): // remove the else block
        break
```